# Multi-class image segmentation with conflicting labels

Tags: deep-learning, multi-class, semi-supervised-learning

I'm trying to perform multi-class semantic segmentation on a corpus made up of several sub-corpora. The difficult part is that across sub-corpora labels are not consistent. That is to say that similar (or same) objects may have different labels. For example, in sub-corpus |A|, where objects A and B have labels "a" and "b", sub-corpus |B| may have correlated objects A and B, but with labels "c" and "d", "f" and "b", etc. However, within each sub-corpus, labels will nevertheless reflect the *differences* between objects; i.e., "a" and "b" will be distinct. So, there are underlying correlations between objects across all examples, and each sub-corpus will appropriately differentiate between them, but I can't rely on, for example, A being "a" across all sub-corpora.

The other important point about the conflicting labels is that they are systematic. For example, in cases where A is labelled "d" in sub-corpus |B|, that "mislabelling" will be totally consistent (i.e., it's not just labelling error). Broadly speaking, this also implies that there will likely be, for example, some object F in |B| labelled "a", so that A and F may very well be the same object.

I've been using a "tiramisu" UNet that's working quite well on single sub-corpora, so I'm confident it will work for the segmentation. I now need to start looking at the whole training set and figuring out how to deal with the inconsistent label problem. Is there some way to perhaps integrate the necessary clustering into the UNet itself; e.g., self-learning or semi-supervised training? For reference, I'm using a customized version of the PyTorch model from: https://github.com/bfortuner/pytorch_tiramisu

Any advice appreciated.